# AxisFault NumberFormatException Invalid date/time

Tags: java, soap, axis, wsdl2java, java-calendar

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service with Java. I need to set a date/time element properly.

`<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="startDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>`

I generated a client jar with Axis 1.4 wsdl2java

I need to send a Calendar type object.

`java.util.Calendar startDate`

In SOAPUI, it accepts the format below.

`<startDate>22/05/2022 14:27:00.000</startDate>`

In code, I tried formatting the date but didn't work. I get the same error every time while getting response.

`AxisFault java.lang.NumberFormatException Invalid date/time`

Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

`xsd:dateTime` expects a value in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format e.g. `2022-05-22T14:27:00.000` which is in the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`. Learn more about it from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

**Note**: The `java.time` API has a constant, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) as a pre-defined pattern.